# open covering and open intervals covering

Tags: real-analysis

A compact set is a set that its each open covering has finite sub-cover.

Since non-empty open set is disjoint union of countable open intervals.
[image]

Is there some connections between open cover and open interval cover?

Comment: has a finite SUB-cover. An open set is not necessarily a disjoint union of countable open intervals, take for example, $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: @qbert $\mathbb{R}=\cup_{n=1}^\infty(-n,n)$

Answer (score 0):

An open interval cover is just a special case of an open cover where the open sets are intervals.

There is no direct connection between this theorem and the definition of a compact set.

Answer (score 0):

If compact set $\displaystyle K=\bigcup_{i\in \Lambda}\mathcal{O}_i$, since $\displaystyle \mathcal{O}_i=\bigsqcup_{k=1}^{n_i}I_{ik}$, so $\displaystyle K=\bigcup_{i\in \hat\Lambda}\mathcal{O}_i$, where $\hat\Lambda$ includes all index of $i,k$. Thus, we have a finite sub-covering denoting $\displaystyle \bigcup_{j=1}^mI_j$. So they are equivalent.